# Request for ffmpeg raw data to mp4 container example

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I have a binary file with raw h264 data which is arranged like that
NAL(SPS), NAL(PPS), NAL(Frame), NAL(SPS), NAL(PPS)....
and i want to mux it (without encode) into a mp4 container.
The muxing.c in the ffmpeg example do the encoding of yuv data, but it is different from my case, and i have no ideas how to change the example to do what i want to do...

I knew the commaned ffmpeg -i h264file -c copy h264.mp4 can do what i want to do, but i have to do it in my program, so i need to know how to use the ffmpeg api to do the same thing, but so far, i cannot find any simple example to do it. Is there anyone has hint on how to do it?? Thanks

Updated, i have write the code as below from the reference, it seems can create the mp4 but the time is not correct, it lost the frame rate information and the time information, it play very fast.

```
av_register_all();

int ret;
AVDictionary *opt = NULL;
//bool is264 = true;
const char * inputFileName = "input.264";
const char * outputFileName = "output.mp4";

AVFormatContext *ic = avformat_alloc_context(); 
if((ret = avformat_open_input(&ic, inputFileName, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
    return -1;//

// Get format info (retrieve stream information)
if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ic, NULL)) < 0)
    return ret; // Couldn't find stream information

for (int i = 0; i < ic->nb_streams; i++) 
{
    AVStream *stream;
    AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;
    stream = ic->streams[i];
    codec_ctx = stream->codec;
    /* Reencode video & audio and remux subtitles etc. */
    if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
        || codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        /* Open decoder */
        ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, avcodec_find_decoder(codec_ctx->codec_id), NULL);
        if (ret < 0) {
            //av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to open decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}

// Dump information about file onto standard error
av_dump_format(ic, 0, inputFileName, 0);

AVFormatContext *oc;

avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc, NULL, NULL, outputFileName);
if (!oc) {
    //printf("Could not deduce output format from file extension: using MPEG.\n");
    //avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc, NULL, "mpeg", outputFileName);
    return -1;
}

AVStream *ist = ic->streams[0];

AVCodec *out_vid_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(oc->oformat->video_codec);
if (NULL == out_vid_codec)
    return -1;  // Couldn't find video encoder

AVStream *out_vid_strm = avformat_new_stream(oc, out_vid_codec);
if (NULL == out_vid_strm)
    return -1;  // Couldn't output video stream

ret = avcodec_copy_context(out_vid_strm->codec, ist->codec);
if (ret < 0)
    return ret;  // Failed to copy context

ret = avio_open(&oc->pb, outputFileName, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
ret = avformat_write_header(oc, NULL);

AVPacket pkt;   

while(1)
{           
    AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;
    ret = av_read_frame(ic, &pkt);
    if (ret < 0)
        break;

    pkt.stream_index = 0;
    in_stream = ic->streams[pkt.stream_index];
    out_stream = oc->streams[pkt.stream_index];


    pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
    pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, (AVRounding)(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
    pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
    pkt.pos = -1;
    //log_packet(ofmt_ctx, &pkt, "out");

    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(oc, &pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error muxing packet\n");
        break;
    }
    av_packet_unref(&pkt);
}

av_write_trailer(oc);
```

Comment: Raw 264 file does not have timing information. Hence you can’t copy timestamps from in_stream to out_stream. You must set the timestamps yourself manually.

Comment: Can you give me some example on how to do it?? Thanks